# Twitter API example query for get all tweets

Tags: twitter

I want to get all tweets from Twitter API (from all users that are public not only who I followed) that have specific language (for example English) and aren't older than 24h
How can I build the query?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot build such a query. Check out the Twitter docs at https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation to see what is possible.